# Gson serialize a List field to string and preserve SerializedName

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I want to serialize a `List<String>` field to `String` while preserving its @SerializedName.
For instance - this is my pojo

```
Class Friend {

    @SerializedName("friendName", alternate = "name")
    String name; 

    @SerializedName("friendlyNames", alternate = "akaNames")
    List<String> nicknames
}
```

I want to serialize this as

```
{
  "friendName": "Friend name goes here", 
  "friendlyNames": "name1:name2:name3"
}
```

Is it possible to use an annotation on top of nicknames and invoke a custom serializer?

I looked at [typeAdaper](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) but I don't see where I can get the SerializedName attribute in that.
The [JsonSerializer](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) field doesn't seem to be applicable at field level.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't need to know the JsonSerialized name value. I was able to do this and test it out and it worked fine.

```
public class MyCustomSerializer implements JsonSerializer<List<String>> {
    private final String CUSTOM_STRING_DELIMITER = ":";
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(List<String> strings, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        String result = String.join(CUSTOM_STRING_DELIMITER, strings);
        return new JsonPrimitive(result);
    }
}
```

later on do this

```
Type listOfStrings = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(listOfStrings, new MyCustomSerializer())
                .create();
```